# Add assign values to variable outside map function

Tags: rust, iterator, closures

So I have a double map block adding values to a variable defined outside the closures.

```
let mut net_forces = vec![Vector3::<f64>::zeros(); n_objs];

r_vec.iter().zip(masses.iter()).enumerate().map(|(i, (r1, m1))| {
    r_vec.iter().take(i)
                        .zip(masses.iter().take(i))
                        .enumerate()
                        .map(|(j, (r2, m2))| {
                            let fij: Vector3<f64> = calculate_force_vec(r1, r2, m1, m2);
                            net_forces[i] = net_forces[i] + fij;
                            net_forces[j] = net_forces[j] + -fij;
                        });
)}
```

r_vec and masses are both vecs, one of Vector3 and one of f64.

I can implement this in a for loop fine by doing a for loop over the outer iteration and collecting the inner map to an empty variable. But I wanted to try and write it all functionally but when I structure it like this the compiler says I need to use move to have access to net_forces.
My issue is if I do move net_forces in, I don't know how to get it back out and I can't see an easy way to collect it out given I need to modify different indices simultaneously.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to map an iterator to `()`. Maybe you meant to use `for_each`?

Comment: Yes thank you! For each is perfect.

Comment: `for_each()` is the correct way to go about it, but for learning purposes do note that there writing almost anything that exhausts the iterator will work too. For example, you can slap a `for ... {}` around the chain of iterators, or you can terminate the chain with something like `.count()`. Even a `.collect::<Vec<_>>()` works because since `()` is zero-sized, a `Vec<()>` doesn't allocate, so `.collect::<Vec<_>>()` is a fancy way of spelling `.count()`.